# The correct way to change the name of the language in the language switch

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I try to change the name of language in language switcher from *Chinese, Simplified(简体中文)* to *中文*. Changing name in admin/config/regional/language/edit/zh-hans affects only English. So the language switcher looks like this:

> en/Chinese, Simplified(简体中文)

I created a function, but on some pages (e.g. node/1), it causes errors.

```
function theme_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
   $variables['content']['#links']['zh-hans']['title'] = '中文';
}
```

The error I get is the following one.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getText() on array in /var/www/mysite/core/includes/theme.inc on line 1697

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check, if the variable is set, to avoid the error:

```
function theme_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['content']['#links']['zh-hans']['title'])) {
    $variables['content']['#links']['zh-hans']['title'] = '中文';
  }
}
```

Comment: Of course, I changed. I described it in 2 nd line

Comment: Did you use admin/config/regional/language/edit/zh-hans/**translate**?

Comment: I tryed `/admin/config/regional/language/edit/en/translate` and `/admin/config/regional/language/edit/zh-hans/translate`

Comment: OK, if this does not help, then you need the preprocess. You only have to check, if the variable is set, to avoid the error. I change my answer.

Comment: thanx, a tryed this, errors doesn't appear until now

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for language switcher block with Language Icons module:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['content']['#links']['zh-hans']['title'])) {
    $variables['content']['#links']['zh-hans']['title']['#text'] = '中文';
    $variables['content']['#links']['zh-hans']['title']['#title'] = '中文'; 
  }
}
```

It just replaces language name and saves country flag. Insert this code in .theme file of your theme and change THEMENAME with name of your theme.